# Output column headers and the non null value coverage under each column as separate rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

Having a dataframe df containing 4 columns A,B,C,D with A,B,C column having both null and non null values. D column has only non null values. Trying to output these column names along with the non null values coverage under each column as separate rows

```
mylist = ['Column', 'Cov']
with open('cov.csv','w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(mylist)
    for i in df.columns:
        j = ((df[i].count())/(df['D'].count()))
        writer.writerows(zip(i,j))
```

However this throws an `TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration` error. What changes should be made to get the desired output. Below is the desired output

```
Column  Cov
A   0.53
B   0.2
C   0.8
D   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with your `writerows` and `zip` usage. `Zip` is for iterables and neither `i` and `j` are iterables. `i` is the column name and `j` is the calculation of counts. So, having identified this we would use `writerow` instead. Here is a full example based off your description and code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0.3,0.4,np.nan],'B':[0.5,np.nan,np.nan],'C':[np.nan, .23 ,.99],'D':[.2, .3, .4]})
```

This gives you:

[image]

With this df, lets run your updated code:

```
mylist = ['Column', 'Cov']
with open('cov.csv','w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(mylist)
    for i in df.columns:
        numerator = df[i].count()
        denominator = df['D'].count()
        ratio = numerator / denominator
        writer.writerow([i, ratio])
```

Then lets check the results with this code:

```
with open('cov.csv', 'r') as file:
    print(file.read())
```

The contents of the csv file:

```
Column,Cov
A,0.6666666666666666
B,0.3333333333333333
C,0.6666666666666666
D,1.0
```

Comment: can you please explain what is meant by iterables in this situation..thought i and j were iterables since their value changes with each iteration..thanks

Comment: @Vj_x49x iterables are objects that you can inspect through iteration (not necessarily in order). A simple example with order: if a=[1,2,3,4] then we can iterate through each value in a using a for loop (for i in a) -- note here that i is not an iterable -- its just one of the values of a. This link: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-iterator-tutorial and this link: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_iterators.asp seem to have useful information. Also, to get the index and the value see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate.